# Creating exclude filter from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a search string that recognised a character from the search.

I want to use it like an `exclude` if the text contains `-`.

It should only exclude if the `-` character has a `space before it` or is at `position 0`.

Search `foo -bar` it should only where foo exists but bar does not.

I created a sample on a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ZvAqXoOQ

The code should work like this, but recognise when to apply the `every(e => !title`.

## foo

```
.filter(movie => {
  const title = movie.title.toLowerCase();
  return search.every(e => title.includes(e.toLowerCase()));
```

## bar

```
.filter(movie => {
  const title = movie.title.toLowerCase();
  return search.every(e => !title.includes(e.toLowerCase()));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick condition based on first letter of a term. Something like this.

```js
const movies = ['foo', 'foo bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'foo baz'].map(title => ({title}))

const search = 'foo -bar'.split(' ')


console.log(
    movies.filter(
      ({title}) => search.every(term => term[0] === '-' ? !title.includes(term.substring(1)) : title.includes(term))
   )
)
```

```js
const movies = ['foo', 'foo bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'foo baz'].map(title => ({title}))

const search = 'foo -'.split(' ')


console.log(
    movies.filter(
      ({title}) => search.every(term => {
        if(term === '-') return true
        
        if(term[0] === '-') return !title.includes(term.substring(1))
        
        return title.includes(term)
      
      })
   )
)
```

Comment: One small problem with that- if only ` - ` (with space before and no text after. Currently, when typing it will show no result until something is typed after '-'. Example here https://codesandbox.io/s/ZvAqXoOQ

Comment: @Ycon The idea is the same: you analyze term according to your reqirements and then use if-else statement to pick condition you need based  on your analysis. So you check `if(term === '-') return true` than `if(term[0] === '-') return !title.includes` etc.

Comment: Great. Lastly, I'm trying to apply your example to some data nested within 'movies'. However, unable to apply the filter to it. It's here (line 12) https://codesandbox.io/s/ZvAqXoOQ. My attempt is `if(x[0] === '#') return genres.includes(f => genres.includes(x.toLowerCase())`

Comment: A slight change to the above. It matches, but only when the full string is there (ie no partial match, as works for the search). Any ideas on that? `https://codesandbox.io/s/ZvAqXoOQ`